# How can i set up a website in CSS to react to different resolutions?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

For a college project, i need to take a website that my teacher gave me in HTML, and set it up so that if the resolution is cut down to a max-width of 640px, i need to take out the picture and nav bar at the side. I'm just unsure as to how i program it in CSS so that i can hide sections when 640px is met? Sorry if this requires alot of explaining but we dont have a textbook for web design right now and i cant find any examples on the schools online database that i could refer to, to figure it out
thanks in advance

Comment: Google responsive design

Comment: http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

Comment: [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: If you Google your exact question, "How can i set up a website in CSS to react to different resolutions?" as @JohnConde suggests, the first result is an introduction to media queries which is exactly what you should use.

Answer (score 3):

The css within this media query will be applied if the screen width is less than 640px. This will work in most modern browsers. Remember this is limited to what you can do with css. If you want to manipulate the dom you will have to use javascript. To hide elements you can set them to *display:none;*

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
  /* css*/
}
```

Very simple demo of this. If the result window becomes less than 640px it will become gray:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKzNz/)

Comment: heads up, you have duplicate px ... `640pxpx`. i tried to fix it, but it required a minimum of 6 character changes.

Comment: Thanks! was a bit too fast there :)

Comment: Just curious, tell me if I'm translating this right: it's saying that @media "all devices" and "those with a maximum width of 640px" should be grey. I'm guessing this because when I try using just "width" the window flashes grey when I have it exactly at 640px.

Comment: You are correct :) Even though I believe it to be rare that you want to set it to an exact width. Usually you would choose a max and minimum width. Then set up different intervals for screens. As in computers, tablets, mobile, mobile landscape etc. Depending on how many screen sizes you want to support.